# loops are not continuing can't figure out why

Tags: c++, iostream

Hey i have this program here

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int MyNum;
  int ComNum;
  MyNum = 5;

   do {
     cout << "Enter a whole number between 1 and 10: ";
     cin >> ComNum;
     if (ComNum > MyNum) {
       cout << "Sorry that is incorrect (Hint: too high)";
     }
     if (ComNum < MyNum) {
       cout << "Sorry that is incorrect (Hint: too low)";
       cin >> ComNum;
     }
   } while(MyNum != ComNum);
   cout << "Correct"
}
```

and i can't figure out why it won't continue running after the first incorrect answer i'm sure i am missing something small and stupid (P.S.) this is a guess my number game if you can't tell from the code

Comment: If `ComNum < MyNum`, why do you read input *again*?

Comment: Fix compiler error at `cout << "Correct"`.

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but get rid of the second `cin >> ComNum;`.

Comment: You're also missing a `return` statement. And a semicolon

Comment: Try and get into the habit of declaring variables closer to where they're used and initializing them at the same time if possible. This makes for far fewer type errors, and you're less likely to slip and leave a variable uninitialized. For example, this code could be `int MyNum = 5;` instead of deferring that initialization for no reason.

Comment: @tadman yeah it's a bad habit i picked up from visual basic

Comment: @GBlodgett thank you that did it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing semicolon is giving an error after correct:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int MyNum;
  int ComNum;
  MyNum = 5;

   do {
     cout << "Enter a whole number between 1 and 10: ";
     cin >> ComNum;
     if (ComNum > MyNum) {
       cout << "Sorry that is incorrect (Hint: too high)";
     }
     if (ComNum < MyNum) {
       cout << "Sorry that is incorrect (Hint: too low)";
       cin >> ComNum;
     }
   } while(MyNum != ComNum);
   cout << "Correct";
}
```

as others have said, the second        cin >> ComNum;
is unnecessary, although it worked on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler with it

Comment: Awesome thank you, this worked perfectly, i was wanting to make sure it was a problem i did and not something else i'm coding this from a chromebook with the beta linux apps feature turned on (using Atom as my code editor) and the compiler i was using is really buggy i will for sure be using this online one

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `cin >> ComNum;` in the IF and fix compiler error `cout << "Correct";`.